# MVC submit button not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using ASP.net MVC 4 with the Razor engine.

I have a page (Index.cshtml) and a controller (HomeController.cs)

I am trying to hook up my submit button to an Action Result in my controller - however i can't seem to get it to fire.

**My HTML :**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitForm", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
      <div class="main-Background">

      ******lots of other html here*******
        <button type="submit" id="btnSave">Save</button>

    </div>
}
```

**My Controller :**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SubmitForm()
        {
          return View();
        }

    }
```

At the moment i havn't implemented a model to pass the values through to the controller, i just wanted to see if i could get the ActionResult SubmitForm to fire.

I have tried `@using (Html.BeginForm())` with no parameters, i have also tried including `[HttpPost]` above my ActionResult, without any luck.

***Edit*** i have also tried using  `<input type="submit" id="btnSave">Save</input>` instead of a button.

Not sure where i am going wrong

Comment: check my answer it will work for you

Comment: Just tried it, didn't work. I think the code you provided is right - just something else is preventing it from working

Comment: can you update your code.

Comment: have you included the parameter in your action method?

Comment: "i can't seem to get it to fire" - what does that mean?

Comment: it means i put a breakpoint in side the ActionResult and it wasn't hit

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee i have updated my code - i think the problem is elsewhere. I will do some digging

Comment: no still didnt upadted it properly wait

Comment: can you try the same after removing the `new {id = "submitform"}`

Comment: still the same I'm afraid

Comment: Controller is not req. in the index page made the change

Comment: Oh right i did try that - just missed it from the edit

Comment: down voters care to comment?

Comment: Use the developer tools in the browser and see what happens when you click the button.

Comment: @Josh Thanks - this led me in the right direction to find the solution. I am using jQuery UI which styled all my buttons - upon disabling this i was able to get the breakpoint to be hit.

Comment: It must be the Jqury validate check the below code 
 $("#fortmid").validate() and you can find which validation holds you 
on 'errorlist'

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It turns out that jQuery was stopping the ActionResult from being hit.

I had a button click event which was "eating up" the ActionResult functionality. I solved this by calling my ActionResult using Ajax.

Comment: @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
I added it up into _Layout and spent few hours in the hell as a result :-)

Comment: Hi, if i removed this jqueryval also i am not getting any result. The same issue is happening for me

Answer (score 4):

You dont need to use `"-Controller"` suffix. Use just `Home` instead of `HomeController`, MVC will convert it for you.

Use

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitForm", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "submitForm" }))
```

instead of

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitForm", "HomeController", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "submitForm" }))
```

---

Full codes

**view**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitForm", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "submitForm" }))
{
      <div class="main-Background">

          ******lots of other html here*******
          <input type="submit" id="btnSave">Save</input>

    </div>
}
```

**And controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitForm()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I'd explain what you changed - that took me a minute , then it was obivous .   Just put the controller name , excluding "Controller" from the actual name

Comment: @ScottSelby, you right, first: answer and second: edit for faster answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer - unfortunately it still doesn't fire

Comment: If these are your real codes, this suggestion must work. There are no problem about codes...

Comment: he said
I have tried @using (Html.BeginForm()) with no parameters, i have also tried including [HttpPost] above my ActionResult, without any luck.

Comment: This is definitely my real code, obviously i have other views/controls/layouts but these should not affect this functionality

Comment: There are tons of example about mvc form post :) just look one of them, and try them. There is no different code.

Comment: Please consider posting this as a comment, not as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitForm", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
  <div class="main-Background">
    ******lots of other html here*******
    <button type="submit" id="btnSave">Save</button>

  </div>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitForm()
{
    return View();
}
```

May be the problem is occurred because of other HTML inside your div so check it out.  Otherwise it works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks but i figured it out and posted an answer explaining why it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

You need to add Html.BeginForm with the parameters. Here is an example:

ActionName – Name of the Action. In this case the name is Create.

ControllerName – Name of the Controller. In this case the name is Home.

FormMethod – It specifies the Form Method i.e. GET or POST. In this case it will be set to POST.

```
http://localhost:60386//Home/Create


@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)

  <input type="submit" value="Create"/>
}


HomeController.cs:
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Person person)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Persons.Add(person);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Create");
            }

            return View(person);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for this input, my BeginForm had HomeController instead of only Home. You solved my problem which was similar to OP :)

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

I had `[Required]` data attributes on my view model preventing the submit from working when the form wasn't filled.

---

I had [two submit buttons in my MVC code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/443047/979621), one for `Submit`, the other for `Cancel`.

Both buttons were firing correctly on data entry, but neither when nothing was entered.

It took me a bit to realize that my view model had `[Required]` field validations in place!

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(actionName: "Index", controllerName: "User", method: FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhoneNumber)
    
    ...
    
    <input type="submit" name="submitAction" value="Verify" />
    <input type="submit" name="submitAction" value="Cancel" />
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    ...
}
```

Controller Method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
public ActionResult Index(UserViewModel viewModel, string submitAction)
{
    switch(submitAction)
    {
        case "Verify": ...
        
        case "Cancel": ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change this `@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitForm", "HomeController", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "submitForm" }))`

to

`@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitForm", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "submitForm" }))`

Explanation : No need to suffix Controller anywhere, it being accepted by default

and in the **Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitForm(string id)
    {

        return View();
    }
```

Explanation : as the Form Method given by you is Post so need to include `[HttpPost]` before the Action and the parameter you were passing was missing in the action method

Comment: it looks like you just took a lot longer to post the exact same answer - that was said to not fix the problem in the other answer;s comments

Comment: i will answer when I read the complete question then wrote the answer, before the answer was updated on my side.

Comment: id is not a parameter, id is htmlattribute.

Comment: really is it so?
i dont think so
@AliRızaAdıyahşi

Comment: oh yeah sorry, html attributes are also bind this way

Comment: but in that way we pass id to action as well

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20748115/html-beginform-not-posting-to-server-despite-submit-button
check the link might help

Comment: are the other pages working fine for you ?

can this `@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitForm", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "submitForm" }))` to `@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))` and create a dummy post method for Index so that, we can know where exactly the problem is

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee  figured it out - i was using jQuery UI to modify all input and buttons, for some reason this was blocking this functionality

Comment: what modification it was doing?