# cshtml view not rendering

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using ASP.net MVC with the razor engine.

I have a page with a button, when the button is clicked i call an `ActionResult` in my controller using Ajax. The Ajax call:

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "/Home/Review",
     success: function (data) {
         //alert("yay");
     }
});
```

My `ActionResult` method is hit fine, however it does not load the view speified.
The code:

```
public ActionResult Review()
{
    return View();
}
```

The current view is `Index.cshtml` when Review() is hit i would like `Review.cshtml` to be rendered on screen. (It should be rendered as a full view, not as partial view inside Index.cshtml)

I have tried - `return View("Review");` `return View("Review.cshtml");` `return View("..\Views\Home\Review.cshtml);`

I can't use - `tml.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post);` (see my other question [MVC submit button not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24431846/mvc-submit-button-not-firing/24433146#24433146))

Comment: The `data` parameter of the `success` callback function, should contain the response from the server.

Comment: You want to include the content of Review.cshtml inside Index ? If not why do you do an ajax call ?

Comment: @NicoD No, i want to load Review instead of index.. like navigating to a different page

Comment: Just submit the form to a specific action Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post); or use a link in this case. No need for ajax.

Comment: Just edited post to show why i cant use that. Also i will be sending some data later so will need ajax anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the response directly to the screen

```
success: function (data) {
   document.write(data)  }
```

Comment: Maybe you should read : [Why is document.write considered a “bad practice”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

After ajax, you should render a partial view to add returning result to main view(index).

**Index.cshtml**

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "/Home/Review",
   success: function (data) {
       $("#container").html(data);
       //alert("yay");
   }
...

<div id="container"></div>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Review()
{

    return PartialView();
}
```

---

If you want to redirect after ajax you can use something like following:

**Index.cshtml**

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "/Home/Review",
   success: function (data) {
       window.location.href = data.url;
   }
...
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Review()
{

    return Json(new { url = "some url" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

Comment: That's for a partial view though, i want to render a full view

Comment: @DNKROZ, if you want to render full page, why you use ajax post?

Comment: Because I'm using jQuery UI buttons and the click handler prevents `Html.BeginForm` from working